# Get selected rows (extjs grid) from dynamic action in APEX

Tags: extjs, grid, oracle-apex

I have apex grid plugin , which writted on ExtJS. It have trigger 'select row' and get one seleted row successfuly. I want to get selected rows from grid in apex dynamic action.
How can I do it?

I don't know extjs and I ask to write more details . Thanks!

Part of grid:

```
Ext.apex.TableGrid = function(table, config){
config = config || {};

// apply config, and a default config
Ext.apply(this, config, {
xtype: "grid",
frame: "true",
autoHeight: true,
autoWidth: true,
collapseFirst: false,
iconCls: 'icon-grid',
loadMask: true,
stripeRows: true,
titleCollapse: true,
frame: true,
multiSelect: true,
cls: "pplab-grid",
listeners: {
  rowclick: function( g, ri, e ){
      $( '#'+config.pluginRegionId ).trigger( "rowclickpplabexttabgrid", { 
        grid: g,
        rowIndex: ri,
        record: g.getStore().getAt( ri )
      } )
  },
  rowdblclick: function( g, ri, e ){
      $( '#'+config.pluginRegionId ).trigger( "rowdblclickpplabexttabgrid", { 
        grid: g,
        rowIndex: ri,
        record: g.getStore().getAt( ri )
      } )
  }  
}
});

var g = this,
fields = config.fields || [], 
cols = config.columns || [],
tableContainer = Ext.get( "report_" + this.regionId + "_catch" ),
emptyTxt = "";

table = Ext.get(table);

if ( !table ) { 
emptyTxt = tableContainer.dom.innerHTML;
tableContainer.dom.innerHTML = "";

table = tableContainer.createChild( {
  tag: "table",
  id: table
} ).set( { empty: true } );
};

var ct = table.insertSibling({
id: this.id || Ext.id()
});

 Ext.apply(this, {
'ds': ds,
'cm': cm,
'sm': new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel( {
  singleSelect: false,
  listeners: {
    rowselect: function( sm, ri, rc ){
      $( '#'+config.pluginRegionId ).trigger( "rowselectpplabexttabgrid", { 
        grid: sm.grid,
        rowIndex: ri,
        record: rc
      } );
    }
  }
} ),
bbar: paging,
viewConfig: { 
  emptyText: emptyTxt,
  deferEmptyText: false
}
});

....
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extend this so users can click on a row and either add it or remove it from a collection of selected rows?

Comment: yes. user selects row in grid, after I want to get selected rows in dynamic action apex.

Comment: Seems like rowclickpplabexttabgrid needs add to an array and rowdblclickpplabexttabgrid needs to delete from an array. Does your triggering code work at all?